# variable of associative array variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array `$arr=array("a"=>array("b"=>123))` 
and I need to do with it something like this:

```
$a='[a][b]';
echo $arr{$a};
```

but it doesnt work;

`echo $arr[a][b];` - works fine, but it's not what I need. =(

PHP manual says:

*if you write $$a[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) then the parser needs to know if you meant to use $a[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as a variable, or if you wanted $$a as the variable and then the [1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)} for the first case and ${$a}[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for the second.* >> [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

but "echo ${$a};" and "echo $arr{$a};" and all the other variations output nothing.

**UPDATE**

in short, I need to delete an element of assotiative array via form.
For example, I have $a=array('abc'=>'def');
and html form

```
<form><input name="deleteIT" value="[abc]"></form>
```

So, after submitting I want to delete from $a variable $deleteIT value.

Comment: Frankly, "what you need" sounds awful.  You might want to reconsider how you've designed this.

Comment: $a is a string, not an array. what is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sean, as you see, array $arr[a][b] outputs '123'. 
I need to output array value, represented in string '[a][b]'.
I need it for editing assitiative arrays dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close enough to what you need?

```
$a = "a,b";
list( $i, $j ) = explode( ",", $a );
echo $arr[$i][$j];
```

---

**Addendum:** The answer above will work if the array `$arr` always has exactly two levels.  If it might have more (or less), something like the following could work:

```
function array_get_nested ( $array, $keys ) {
    $value = $array;
    foreach ( $keys as $index ) {
        $value = $value[ $index ];
    }
    return $value;
}
```

The function above takes two arrays as arguments: one containing the value we want, and another listing the keys we need to locate it in the first array.  For example, if we have an array like this:

```
$arr = array( "a" => array( "b" => array( "c" => 123 ) ) );
```

then

```
echo array_get_nested( $arr, array( "a", "b", "c" ) );
```

would print `123`.

Converting string keys into an array suitable for the second argument to `array_get_nested()` depends on how the keys are formatted, but it could be as simple as calling `explode()` with a suitable delimiter.  For example, the last line of code above could be rewritten as:

```
$k = "a,b,c";
echo array_get_nested( $arr, explode( ",", $k ) );
```

To modify nested arrays, we can use a similar function:

```
function array_set_nested ( &$array, $keys, $value ) {
    $ref =& $array;
    foreach ( $keys as $index ) {
        $ref =& $ref[ $index ];
    }
    $ref = $value;
}
```

Note that PHP conveniently "autovivifies" arrays for us, so we can, for example, take a previously undefined variable `$foo` and turn it into a three-level nested array simply with:

```
array_set_nested( $foo, array( "a", "b", "c" ), 123 );
```

Comment: Thanx Ilmari, but it doesn't. I need to echo value of assotiative array, represented by string.

Comment: @EL2002: OK, so does the string _have_ to look like `"[a][b]"`, or is some other format (like my `"a,b"`) acceptable?  And does the array always have exactly two levels, or does the solution need to deal with arbitrarily deeply nested arrays?

Comment: @ Ilmari Karonen: string "[a][b]" may look different and represent the array's "address" of variables and their values. And yes, $a can be deeper and be whatever can be in array.
For example, if $arr is array("a"=>array("b"=>array("c"=>123))) and I vant to "echo $arr[a][b][c]" dynamically, I need something like "$a='[a][b][c]'" and echo it "echo $arr$${$a}" or something like that.

Comment: @EL2002: OK, I expanded my answer; does that help any?

Comment: @ Ilmari Karonen: It's not, but thanx anyway. I was hoping that there's possibility of using pure "variable variable" with associative arrays. But it seems it's not possible. So thanx and I vote your answer.